# Is it possible to align the BackgroundImage of a ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, listview, alignment

I am assigning an image (star icon) as a background image to my listview in a C# winforms application.

```
listview1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("star.png");
```

Is it possible to align the image so that it appears somewhere other than the top left-hand corner?

Comment: There's a pretty plain answer offered in this thread.  What's the hang-up, what else do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want alignment, use the Image property, not BackgroundImage.